# avconv incorrect length when splitting video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, avconv

avconv used to work fine for me in 13.10, but now it doesn't. I'm using it in the same way as before, for example:

```
avconv -ss 1971 -t 2216 -i x.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -metadata track="7"  "d32.mp4"
```

terminal output:

```
avconv version 9.13-6:9.13-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
  built on May  9 2014 13:34:03 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'x.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf55.12.100
  Duration: 01:06:14.76, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 848 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(und): Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p, 854x480, 716 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0.1(und): Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 125 kb/s
Output #0, mp4, to 'd32.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    track           : 7
    encoder         : Lavf54.20.4
    Stream #0.0(und): Video: libx264, yuv420p, 854x480, q=2-31, 716 kb/s, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Stream #0.1(und): Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, stereo, 125 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press ctrl-c to stop encoding
frame=50092 fps=6618 q=-1.0 Lsize=  197157kB time=2003.60 bitrate= 806.1kbits/s    
video:165125kB audio:30720kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.670179%
```

The length of the output should be 4 minutes and 5 seconds, but it is over 30 minutes. Does any one know what is going on or have a suggestion?

Comment: Try downloading the most recent static build of `ffmpeg` from the [FFmpeg Dwonload](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html#LinuxBuilds) page. I'm interested to know if it works as expected.

Comment: It has the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for trying. Can you show the command and the complete console output? ...and only now do I realize my typo in the first comment.

Answer (score 1):

I used `-t` as an ending time instead of a duration.

The correct way to use `-t` is to specify how long should the output video be, in other words in this case the value in the parameter `-ss` needs to be substituted.